# How to know when my timer has stopped even when the app isn’t running

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, timer, cron

This could be something like the stories on Instagram or other similar Social Media platforms, the stories you post will only stay for 24 hours and then disappear on its own, even if the app isn't running. I've made something similar, take a look at the code:

```
// Update the notification database with the deadline date
let today = Date()
let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)!
// Format the date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: modifiedDate)
self.DBRef.child("Notifications").child(chosenUser).child(selectedStoryID).updateChildValues(["Due Date" : formattedDate]) { (error, ref) in
    if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
        print("Failed to set deadline with error \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Deadline set")
    }
}
```

What this code does is that it takes the current date and time and adds 24 hours to it and stores it in the database. Take a look at the following code snippet:

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
let deadline = dateformatter.date(from: notificationTableData.storyDeadline)

_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in

    let seconds = Int(deadline?.timeIntervalSinceNow ?? 0.0)
    self.timeLeft.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", (seconds / 3600), ((seconds % 3600) / 60), (seconds % 60))

    if seconds == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        // Remove this node from the database
    }
}
```

What this code snippet does is that it retrieves the date from the database and displays it in my app. What I want is that when the current date and time is equal to the deadline's date and time, I want to remove the particular node (I've marked it in the screenshot below) from the Firebase database even if the app isn't running.

[image: Database]

Comment: Do you need instruction on removing from a database or checking the time? Please clarify.

Comment: Hey I know how to remove the node from the database but I don't know how to remove it when the timer has ended even if the app isn't running

Comment: I can think of 2 possible options right now. Either you check if the timer has expired before displaying anything on the screen, and then delete if necessary, or create a separate non-Swift program that is constantly checking your database. The latter could be done with python, and could be done on something like a raspberry pi. The first option is probably easier, but if you really want to delete while the app isn’t running, then I would look at something like this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yylnC3dr_no

Comment: Hmm cool cool, I'll take a look at that :)

Comment: The flaw with this design is if the user never logs back in the data stays on the server. What you really need is a cron job + cloud functions. The cron job would be a timer that would fire once a day and that would trigger a cloud function to delete said data. Read through these [Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bswift%5Dcron) to get a better feel for that